# How to filter data from one array based on another array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose i have 2 array
`arr1=["a","b","c","d","e"]`
based on `arr2 = [1,3]`
Required output is `arr1 = ["b","d"]`

Comment: Please ask the question clearly, either modify the question or provide the code snippet for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
valueArray = ["a","b","c","d","e"]; // arr1
indexArray = [1,3]; // arr2

valueArray = indexArray.map(index => valueArray[index]);

console.log(valueArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

just do the following order:

```js
const arr1=["a","b","c","d","e"];
const arr2 = [1,3];
const filteredArray = arr1.filter((_,index)=>{
 return arr2.includes(index)
});
console.log(filteredArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the value of the first array with the index provided in the second array. You can achieve that with the following approach

```
arr2.forEach(value => d.push(arr1[value]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map:

```
const arr3 = arr2.map(i => aar1[i])
```